# ms word curly brackets for bulleted list

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am trying to make a bulleted list where some elements have the same description. I don't want to repeat the same description 3 times.
Is there a way to put a big curly brackets around them?
Like this:

[image: Curly Bracket around Bulleted List]

Or something similar would be fine too

Comment: tried the "draw" functionalities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than leave this as unanswered:

Per @D0rf Try the "draw" functionalities.

In Word 2007 this can be Insert > Illustrations - Shapes, Right Brace.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the "Shapes --> Right Brace" graphic image answer...

As you have already presented an example, using this - enter the 3 bullet points, and move cursor back to the Text2 line Heading/Label, then press =>Tab key (just after the label).
Insert the "Shapes --> Right Brace" drawing shape and resize to fit between the top and bottom of the 1-3 list items (as preferred).

Use the detailed "Layout" window to then edit features of your "curly bracket" shape. You should consider setting the shape's Text Wrap mode to "In front of text", and that the "Move object with Text" is ticked. Exit the Layout window, and on the page area you should see the object's "anchor" on the left side of the page. Click and drag this anchor icon, so that it sits just higher than the Text2 line (it sits on the left side of the page, which is ok). It looks like it's positioned between Text1 & Text2 lines (but much closer to top of Text2 line).

Using the Layout window again to edit the settings of the shape, you can then "lock the anchor" position. Exit the window.

The above adjustments, should allow more robust editing of your 3 Text labels and 1 Description text, with less chance of the Right Brace/Bracket from shifting when editing the text, or allowing slight adjustments to your text formatting.

You should be able to set a tab position (on the ruler) on the Text2 line just after the Right Brace shape object, to start typing your Description.